# Why SDK version in recovery is different from SDK version in build.prop

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, android-sdk

I have Nexus 5 running RR 7.1.2 (Nougat) and of course the SDK is 25, but in TWRP Recovery i'm using ADB Shell and type `getprop ro.build.version.sdk' it say 22 (Lollipop)?

I do a clean install and upgrade TWRP still the same, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recovery is a miniature OS in itself, built with separate sources from the OS. For your case, the recovery is built from Lollipop source. This does not affect anything, for this SDK level is not representative of actual OS SDK level and therefore should not be used in any updater-script, etc.

Comment: the result is different if i flash a flashabe zip, it should be for SDK 25 but the outcome is for SDK 22

Comment: Can you point me to the flashable zip? Common scripts using SDK version, e.g. Xposed, grabs it from `/system/build.prop`.

Comment: Im flashing my own flashable zip, getprop at sh file not in updater-script

Comment: @AhmadFikri Then it's your own fault - you need to write it so it mounts `/system` then reads the info from `/system/build.prop`.

Comment: Im pretty much sure that i put mount -o remount,rw /system before read getprop and still read the SDK as 22

Comment: `getprop` always grabs properties as defined by the kernel in use. As said, the recovery is a mini OS and thus runs its own minimal kernel. There is a reason why other zips are not using it - it just isn't the right tool for the situation.